# Enable Rs485 using timer555

Tags: uart, modbus

I'm looking for some help with a PCB design i'm doing, i want to connect a power analyzer thar requites Modbus protochol, using 485 halfduplex
For that to work i need to enable a disable  the rs485 tranductor via gpio or timer555.
i copy pasted this :

http://homepage.eircom.net/~nigelbrooke/Electronics_Projects/RS485_adapter_raspberry_pi.html

I copied the configuration above to se my raspberry as master.

-The would be any problems with the modbus timeout? (i set it like the example at 40us)

-is it a safer solution to set the enable using gpio/mcp23017(i2c)?

Comment: What is *copy pasted*? Assuming that means building the same schematic, there are several config options described in that post, which one did you use?

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, i used the mode where the timer control the enable of the rs485, i used that same r and c in the timer in order to achieve the same timeout .